# Managing multiple svn repos from TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created two repositories on a debian server. One svn repo, **dev**, will contain files and code used by engineers at the company. The other repo, **doc**, will contain sales docs, quotes etc that is to be used by the management/sales staff.

Given that the two repos usage requirements are different and the users that will use them have different levels of computer skills I want to be able to apply different management styles to each repository.

One such example, and my current issue, is that I want the **doc** repo to have auto-props enabled to add `svn:needs-lock` property to all files. This is a request from sales and management as they are not confident with using the SVN yet (thus they want to stick to a lock-modify-unlock versioing model).

However I don't want to apply these restrictions to the **dev** repository.

So through the TortoiseSVN client I am able to modify the subversion config file to enable auto-props etc.

But how can I manage these to repos that are on the same server and use the same client to satisfy this svn:needs-lock issue?

Is there are better way of approaching this concept of having two repos that **need** to have different levels of restrictions.

Note: we are a small company and have no IT admin as such. The engineers are required to administer the IT as a side task of normal work. So solutions need to be simple enough to not warrant constant maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify and reword your question a bit. Your engineers who use **dev** repository want to use [*copy-modify-merge*](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/version-control-basics/#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge.dia-1) versioning model (better for non-binary textual content, e.g. for source code) and non-technical users will stick to a [*lock-modify-unlock*](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/version-control-basics/#svn.basic.vsn-models.lock-unlock.dia-1) (better for binary files, e.g. PSDs, DOCXs, XSLs etc...) model with repo **doc**.

- *Copy-modify-merge* is the default versioning model with Apache Subversion and you don't have to perform any customization for the **dev** repo and/or on your techs clients.
- In order to force *Lock-modify-unlock* model to **doc** repository you can perform the following maintenance tasks:

  1. Adjust client's SVN 'config' to automatically apply `svn:needs-lock` property on all newly added files. This task can be completed by enabling auto-props in Subversion config on client with `enable-auto-props=yes` and specifying auto-props pattern in the `[auto-props]` config area. See [SVNBook for details on the runtime config area](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/) (you can automate the process with a AD security policy) BTW,
  2. Set `svn:needs-lock` property recursively on the repository root node to apply it to all items you currently have in the **doc** repository,
  3. Create a Subversion hook script for the **doc** repo that will check whether `svn:needs-lock` is set on binary files and denies the commit if the property is not present.
     The following article should be helpful: ["Automatic lock-modify-unlock"](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Automatic_lock-modify-unlock).

Comment: This is more-or-less exactly what I want to do with the exception that each user will have both repositories checked out. In general people with predominantly use **dev** or **doc** but there are plenty of use cases where the employees will need to modify files in both repositories. So is there a way of combining bullet one and bullet two on one client machine, without conflicts? Can I possibly use hooks to achieve this.